# "The system cannot find the path specified." whenever i try to run php via cmd

Tags: php, windows, windows-8, cmd

I have Windows 8 and PHP 5.5 installed on the following path:

C:\www\bin\php-5.5.13

Whenever i open CMD and type "php" it throws this:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.2.9200]
(c) 2012 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\jd>php
The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.
```

I have no idea why it throws it TWICE. I looked at my PATH variable, and i added php installation path into my PATH variable. I typed "php" again and i got the same error:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.2.9200]
(c) 2012 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
C:\Users\jd>php

The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.
```

But when i type "php.exe" it works...

Can anybody help me? this is driving me crazy. I tried looking for AutoRun keys in HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor\AutoRun and
HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor\AutoRun

but i found nothing

Comment: What does `where php` print?

Comment: Hello! it prints: C:\www\bin\php.bat

Comment: You got it. Open that file in your favourite editor and find out what's doing wrong (or just remove it).

Comment: It was it, thank you! i can't believe i missed it.  Please make a full answer so i can upvote you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message triggered by Windows command prompt when a command is not found is a different one:

> "php" is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file

Thus you do have a `php` executable somewhere in your `PATH`. However, that message doesn't seem to be generated by PHP. To find out what's getting ran you can use:

```
where php
```

You say you got this:

```
C:\www\bin\php.bat
```

That's a batch file that doesn't belong to the official PHP distribution.